# Crash when setting up managed object context

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Here is my AppDelegate.h, persistentStoreCoordinator and managedObjectModel methods.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class ViewController;    

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>{
UIWindow *window;
ViewController *viewController;

@private
NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext_;
NSManagedObjectModel* managedObjectModel_;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic)  IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel* managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*  
              persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end

-(NSManagedObjectModel*)managedObjectModel{
if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
    return managedObjectModel_;
}
managedObjectModel_ = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
return managedObjectModel_;
}

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)persistentStoreCoordinator{

if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
NSString* dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    
 NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSURL* storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Shapes2.sqlite"]];

NSError* error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] 
initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

The problem starts in the `persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];` line in the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method. When it tries to execute `[self managedObjectModel]`, it goes to the `managedObjectModel` method above and crashes in the `managedObjectModel_ = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];` line.

I think the problem is somewhere else...so if you see any problem, please let me know.

Thank you for time!

I've been reading the "Pro Core Data for iOS" book, writing code up to p.147 in Chap5.
Up to this point, the program built and ran with no problem, but as soon as I added the line below in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method, it gave me the error as follows "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

The line I added was :

```
viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

I followed the code in the program many times, but didn't understand what went wrong...

If you are reading this book, I'd appreciate your help...thank you.

Comment: What does your managedObjectContext property declaration look like?

Comment: Hard to jump on conclusion without looking at actual code :(, But something is related to unimplemented message. something like have you Synthesized managedObjecxtContext before you do something like self.managedObjectContext

Comment: It's impossible to debug this problem without being able to see more of your code. Please post as much relevant code as possible. While the crash is occurring when the line you've posted is executed, the actual problem is undoubtedly somewhere else.

Comment: @dontCheckMyBlog
Sorry for my late reply. You were right. I haven't synthesized the managedObjecxtContext in my AppDelegate.m.

Jeremy and Andrew Madsen:  Thank you for your time, guys!

Answer (score 3):

```
managedObjectModel_ = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
```

In your managedObjectModel method, this is directly assigning an autoreleased object to your private ivar. When you later use this, it is probably deallocated. It should read

```
managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, too. I tried it, but I got an error message: "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'". I think we don't need this 'retain' since iOS 5. do we? Thanks again...

Comment: I assumed you werent using ARC because you had some retain properties, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: no, I think you are right @jrturton, the NSManagedObjectModel is being autoreleased

Comment: try with self.managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];